# django template not able to display values.X-MS-Has-Attach

Tags: python, django, email-attachments

i made a class for fetching email messages, this works.

```
import logging
import poplib
from email import parser


class email(object):
    '''
    this class checks an email address and returns the messages in that email
    '''
    def __init__(self, url, user, pw):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        self.url  = url
        self.user = user
        self.pw   = pw

    def getEmail(self):
        try:
            pop_conn = poplib.POP3_SSL(self.url)
            pop_conn.user(self.user)
            pop_conn.pass_(self.pw)
        except Exception, e:
            logging.warning('was not able to connect to email server')
            logging.info('%s', e )
            raise RuntimeError('was not able to connect: %s', e)
        try:
            #Get messages from server:
            messages = [pop_conn.retr(i) for i in range(1, len(pop_conn.list()[1]) + 1)]
            # Concat message pieces:
            messages = ["\n".join(mssg[1]) for mssg in messages]
            #Parse message into an email object:
            messages = [parser.Parser().parsestr(mssg) for mssg in messages]
            print type(messages), "type is list"
            headers = { key.replace('-', '_'): value for (key, value) in messages.iteritems() }
            setattr(messages, 'headers_underscore', headers)
            return messages
        except Exception, e:
            logging.warning('was not able to get emails')
            logging.info('%s', e )
            raise RuntimeError('was not able to get Emails: %s', e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = 'url.com'
    user = 'foo'
    pw = "bar"
    t=email(url, user, pw)
    message = t.getEmail()
    for message in message:
        print type(message), "message type is instance"
        print message['subject'], message['from'], message['to']
        print message['X_MS_Has_Attach']
```

Then my django view calls the class to gets the messages, and I send those messages to my template. This too works.

```
            t=email(accounts[0]['url'].replace('http://', "")[:-1], 
                    accounts[0]['user'], accounts[0]['pw'])
            message = t.getEmail()
            context = {'messages': message}
            return render(request, 'email/emails.html', context )
```

Then in my template I display the the relevant fields in a table

```
    {% for values in messages %}  

        <tr>
        <td>{{values.from}}</td>
        <td>{{values.to}}</td>
        <td>{{values.subject}}</td>
        <td>{{values.body}}</td>
        <td>{{values.X-MS-Has-Attach}}</td>
        </tr>
{% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

this works except for the last part "`{{values.X-MS-Has-Attach}}`" on that part I get `Could not parse the remainder: '-MS-Has-Attach' from 'values.X-MS-Has-Attach`. Why can my class and django view show if it has an attachment, `print`message['X-MS-Has-Attach'] works, but not the template.

I would love to be able to view or link to the attachment but really I just need to know if it has one (and what the attachment is named).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hyphen (minus sign) is understood by Django to be a minus sign :)
So you cannot use it in template variable names.

I looked at the docs for the email.Message class, which shows that you can get all the headers and their values using the items() method.

So, the simple solution is to convert all the header names from hyphen to underscore.

This should work:

```
for message in messages:
    headers = { key.replace('-', '_'): value for (key, value) in message.items() }
    setattr(message, 'headers_underscore', headers)
```

Now if you access `message.headers_underscore` in your template you'll get the underscore version of the headers.  Eg:

```
{{ message.headers_underscore.X_MS_Has_Attach }}
```

But I'll also point out that X-MS-Has-Attach isn't really the best way to find attachments in an email, since it's a Microsoft-specific extension and not everyone uses Microsoft email products.  The way to do it is to examine the MIME structure of the email.  I think the python email classes have some helpers to make this easy.. look at the docs I linked above.

Basically you need to call `message.is_multipart()` and if that's true then call `message.get_payload()`, which returns an iterable of Message objects.  You have to then look at the headers/content-type of each of those and decide what to do with it.

Comment: thanks for your response, that solved my tag error but i am getting. object has no attribute 'iteritems with your line

Comment: Are you using python 3?  In that case use .items () instead of .iteritems ().  But it is also possible that the message object is not actually a dict, but just something that looks a little bit like a dict but does not implement these methods.. in which case I woudl need to see the code or docs for that class to understand the best way to approach this.

Comment: the class is something i "made", i updated my question with the full code of my class with your lines added, i still get an error with .iteritems(). when i have it print the type(message) it says its a list not a dict. i did not see any links to documentation. i am using python 2.7. thanks again for your help.

Comment: use items() not iteritems()

Comment: "'list' object has no attribute 'items'"

Comment: You need to apply the rewrite (of hypen to underscore to the MESSAGE, not the message list.  See my code.

Comment: i was adding your code after the function returned. needed to added it to the function. thanks for your help, and patience.